# Effect of ffmpeg "-clev" and "-slev" switches on non-surround audio

Tags: ffmpeg

Do the `-clev` and `-slev` switches have any effect on non-surround audio (e.g., mono and stereo) or are they safely ignored in the absence of the center and surround channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the functions that make of these switches check for the presence of a center or side/back channels, correspondingly.